# Posting to a remote server in a spring controller method

Tags: java, php, spring

I have this controller function

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = { "/send_now" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void send_now()throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
//HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/batch_insert/sender.php");
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://hookb.in/vaPG2gkm");

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender", "TRADER"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "4463839399393"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
client.close();
}
```

that i am trying to post to and see the results here https://hookbin.com/bin/vaPG2gkm

Eventually, i want to be able to capture the posted data in a php script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
require ('config.php');
require ('db_class.php');
$db = new MySQLDatabase;


$post = file_get_contents('php://input');


$msg = rand(30,100);


$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$phone = $data['phone'];
$sender = $data['sender'];

$msg = 'This was sent via the Api';
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql="insert into clickatellout (sender,receiver,msg,msgtype,status,flag,scheduledtime) 
                              values ('".$sender."','".$phone."','".$msg."','SMS:TEXT','Send','1','".$time."')";
$db->query($sql);
echo 'ok';
```

when i run the method `send_now` no data is posted and i get this warning in my console

> WARNING: Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [void]:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate standard
>   serializer (of type
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer): Class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory can not
>   access a member of class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer with modifiers
>   "private"

Why is the function not posting data?.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your `send_now` method is returning void which Jackson is trying to serialize. To fix this issue you can try to either return something or add the following annotation to your method:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
```

Comment: The jackson error goes away but no data is visible on hookbin.